How to train Hugging Face Model On Multiple Datasets?
I am trying to fine tune a model based on two datasets, following the example on the Hugging Face website, I have my model training on the Yelp Review dataset, but I also want to train my model on the Short Jokes dataset.
These two datasets are picked just to eximplify that the datasets I would like to fine tune the model on are totally unrelated.
I have seen the interleave_datasets function, but im not sure if its exactly what i should be using.
I've tried this to train on one dataset:
from datasets import load_dataset

yelp_dataset = load_dataset("yelp_review_full")
jokes_dataset = load_dataset("short-jokes")

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, Trainer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-cased")

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = yelp_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

small_train_yelp_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_yelp_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))

# Where do these go?
small_train_short_jokes_dataset = jokes_dataset["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_short_jokes_dataset = jokes_dataset["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))

from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)

from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=small_train_yelp_dataset,
    eval_dataset=small_eval_yelp_dataset,

)

trainer.train()


How would I train my model on two different sets at one time?
